# Duplicate resources issue while generating Signed .AAB file in react-native project

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, npm

First, when I tried to generate a signed APK file from the VSCode terminal I got this issue. I tried every command to resolve this issue but none of them seems to work for me. I tried running this command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Deleted mipmap and raw folders from the android res folder, it helps me to generate.AAB file but when I upload it to Playstore the new app update gets crashed, I don't know it's because of this issue or something else. Tried deleting node modules and installing them again, also made some changes in my **react.gradle** file:

```
doLast {
def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
    File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/${resSuffix}");
    if (originalDir.exists()) {
        File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/${resSuffix}");
        ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
    }
 }
 moveFunc.curry("drawable-ldpi").call()
 moveFunc.curry("drawable-mdpi").call()
 moveFunc.curry("drawable-hdpi").call()
 moveFunc.curry("drawable-xhdpi").call()
 moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxhdpi").call()
 moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxxhdpi").call()
 moveFunc.curry("raw").call()
 }
```

And the most hectic part is when I delete the raw and mipmap folders, some of the images seem not to appear in the app, and again to rid of that issue I've to command this:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

because my APK file didn't sync with the react-native code or the modified code. I'm so stuck with this issue because it's kind of creating a problem loop for me, try to solve one issue another pops up, and I'm not able to update my app in Playstore since 3days, Please help me guys, It would be so helpful, Thank you in advance!!

Comment: will recommend not to do changes to react.gradle ,  try to clean raw folder and and drawable one as well. then ./gradlew clean.   then I will recommend using some crashlytics tool to track the store based application crash ( firebase has free tier )

Comment: @MonkeyDLoofi I tried reverting code from react.gradle file and tried using command ./gradlew clean still not solving the issue

Comment: Still getting 'Duplicate resources' issue while generating signed aab file from Android Studio

Comment: do not generate from android studio! use the basic bundler command

Comment: can you mention the command here....?

Comment: cause the last command I used to generate a signed file from the terminal created this issue, so hope the command you recommend will work

Comment: cd android; ./gradlew bundleRelease should do the trick

Comment: still getting 'Duplicate resources' exception while running through this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241638/discussion-between-ayush-katuwal-and-monkey-d-loofi).